# Replace an element with random numbers in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, random

Let's say I have a vector called `numsVec`, and I want to replace all occurences of the number `10` in that vector with some random number in a given range.

This is my way to do it:

```
auto it = std::find(numsVec.begin(), numsVec.end(), 10);
for(it; it != numsVec.end(); it++) {
    *it = rand() % 9 + 1;
}
```

This worked and replaced all `10`s with some other random number between 1 & 9; but I got this warning.

> warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
>      for(it; it != numsVec.end(); it++)

I want to know why and how to get rid of that warning?
And by the way I wonder if I can use [std::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/) to do the same. If yes, can someone provide a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Following the comments that say the code I provided did not fit what I am trying to achieve. I might be doing it the wrong way. So allow me to simply ask how to replace a given element value with some random numbers.

**Edit 2:**

Thanks for the comments, and I got rid of the warning by doing:

```
for(; it != numsVec.end(); it++) {
        *it = rand() % 9 + 1;
    }
```

Because the way I did that seems wrong. I still have to ask my original question:

**How do I replace an element with some random numbers?**

Comment: by leaving out `it` : `for(; it != numsVec.end(); it++)`

Comment: @RickAstley I tried your way, and now it says: `warning: label 'it' defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
     it : for(; it != numsVec.end(); it++)`, why?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but what you've described does not fit the code you have. It will overwrite all elements with 'random' values starting from first `10`, regardless of what value they have.

Comment: @keltar oh, I didn't notice that,  I saw all `10` got replaced, so I thought it worked. If I did the wrong way, can you show me a right way to do it?

Comment: @TheodoreTang many ways, shortest would probably be `for(auto &i : numsVec) { if(i == 10) { i = rand() % 9 + 1; } }`

Comment: @TheodoreTang and I'm fairly sure Rick Astley haven't meant for you to actually put `it:` in the code. The code that was suggested starts after `:`.

Comment: @keltar I got what Rick Astley meant. But since you said I did the wrong way with that code, even though I got rid of the warning now, and I edited my question, can you show me a right way to do that? Because I currently do not know how.

Comment: @TheodoreTang thought I already did. Since vector isn't sorted or otherwise indexed, you have to iterate through all elements, check value and, if condition matches, replace it.

Comment: @keltar Understood now, sorry for missing that before.

Comment: you can use find_if if the if is more complex than a simple equality

Comment: Start reading here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random , http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Comment: I would iterate over the container with std::find, replacing the value directly through the iterator. You cannot use std::replace_if because it replaces with a constant value.

Comment: rand() % 9 + 1;  // That's an anti-pattern. See https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3551.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain `find` calls but in this case I think the clearest option is going to be a simple self-rolled loop since you have to touch every element regardless of exact implementation:

```
for(auto it : numsVec)
{
    if(*it == 10)
    {
        *it = rand() % 9 + 1;
    }
}
```